# What replaces get_course_category_tree() in Moodle 2.5?

Tags: php, function, moodle

I've followed a [Tutorial](http://docs.moodle.org/dev/Adding_courses_and_categories_to_the_custom_menu) on Moodle.org on how to extend the custom menu and I'm receiving this error message in Moodle 2.5:

> Function get_course_category_tree() is deprecated, please use course renderer or coursecat class, see function phpdocs for more info

The code works, but I would like to upgrade the code for Moodle 2.5. I've found documentation on replacement functions.

Below is the code directly from the tutorial. I need to replace get_category_tree().

```
class theme_mytheme_core_renderer extends core_renderer {
  protected function render_custom_menu(custom_menu $menu) {
    global $CFG;
    require_once($CFG->dirroot.'/course/lib.php');
    $branch = $menu->add(get_string('courses', 'theme_mytheme'), null, null, 10000);
    $categorytree = get_course_category_tree();
    foreach ($categorytree as $category) {
        $this->add_category_to_custommenu($branch, $category);
    }
    return parent::render_custom_menu($menu);
  }
}
```

Here is the [documentation](http://docs.moodle.org/dev/Courses_lists_upgrade_to_2.5#One_course%3a_core_course_renderer%3a%3acoursecat_coursebox.28.29) for the new functions. I've tried all three of the following functions with no success. Does anyone have any thoughts or pointers?

```
 core_course_renderer::coursecat_coursebox()
 core_course_renderer::coursecat_courses()
 core_course_renderer::coursecat_tree()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use $courses = get_courses($categoryid) to get the result.